# When useing varargs parameter in function I get 'Passing value as a vararg is only allowed inside a parenthesized argument list'

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I have the following function -

```kotlin
 private suspend inline fun addAuthenticationCycleToCall(
        authenticationBody: AuthenticationBody,
        shouldReturnValue: Boolean,
        vararg calls: () -> Resource<*>
    ): Resource<*> {

        val authenticationTokenResult = authenticationRepository.getAuthenticationToken(authenticationBody)

        if (authenticationTokenResult is Resource.Exception) return authenticationTokenResult


        var cycleBodyResult : Resource<*> = Resource.Loading<Nothing>()
        calls.forEach { call ->
            cycleBodyResult = call()
            if (cycleBodyResult is Resource.Exception) return cycleBodyResult
        }

        val terminateResult = authenticationRepository.terminateAuthenticationToken(TerminateAuthenticationBody())
        if (terminateResult is Resource.Exception) return terminateResult

        return if (shouldReturnValue) cycleBodyResult else terminateResult
    }
```

what I want is the ability to wrap N function calls with `authenticationRepository.getAuthenticationToken()` and end with `authenticationRepository.terminateAuthenticationToken()` .

So, I tried to use varargs in my function as a paramter so I can put as many functions as I want. The thing is, when trying to use this function, like in this example -

```kotlin
suspend fun performIntervalCycle(authenticationBody: AuthenticationBody): Resource<*> =

        addAuthenticationCycleToCall(authenticationBody, false) {
            authenticationRepository.getDeviceConfiguration()
        }
```

I have a compiler error saying -

`Passing value as a vararg is only allowed inside a parenthesized argument list`

And when trying to fix the parenthesises like this -

```kotlin
 suspend fun performCycleForOffenderInformation(
        authenticationBody: AuthenticationBody,
        tags: List<TagItem>
    ): Resource<*> =

        addAuthenticationCycleToCall(authenticationBody, true, {
            offenderRepository.getOffendersInformation(OffendersInformationBody(sharedPreferences.deviceId, sharedPreferences.token, tags))
        })
```

I got the error -

`Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body`

1. How do I fix these compiler error?
2. Will it work using varargs lambdas to my use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function calls as `lambda` only when the last parameter is a function parameter, with `varargs` you might basically be passing unknown number of lambdas, so compiler does not allow it, you should move it inside `)` braces

```
CoroutineScope(Dispaters.Main).launch{   
    addAuthenticationCycleToCall(authenticationBody, false, {
        authenticationRepository.getDeviceConfiguration()
    })
}
```

and if you want to pass multiple functions

```
addAuthenticationCycleToCall(authenticationBody, false, {
       authenticationRepository.getDeviceConfiguration()
   },{
       authenticationRepository.getDeviceConfiguration()
   })
```

Comment: Thank you, but please look what happens when I try your approach - I get the `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` error as I showed in the main post.

Comment: have wrapper it inside coroutine scope using launch, check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

1. parameter 'calls' in addAuthenticationCycleToCall function should be suspend like:

   ```
   vararg calls: suspend () -> Resource<*>
   ```
2. and then you jast pass function with authenticationRepository::getDeviceConfiguration or if it is not suspend like:

   ```
   addAuthenticationCycleToCall(authenticationBody, false, suspend { authenticationRepository.getDeviceConfiguration() })
   ```
3. you should invoke lambdas now with launch

P.S. sorry for editing, I did not get the question at first :)

Comment: Please look at the main post, I have already tried doing so and got a coroutine body error

Comment: @Tenfour04  i've just ran it, i don't get where i could be wrong

Comment: I was talking to the person asking the question.